# C++ Template Function errors via Cygwin - Redefinition of Function in hpp file

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

My program compiles through VS Code using the Microsoft compiler, however it will **NOT** compile using Cygwin (through the cygwin terminal).

The errors are all nearly identicial and repeat on every function in the class Node (node.h file)

```
Node.hpp:5:1: error: redefinition of ‘Node<value_type>::Node(value_type&, Node<value_type>*, Node<value_type>*)’
    5 | Node<value_type>::Node(value_type& newData, Node* next, Node* prev) {
```

As I understand: the Node.hpp file is for implementation and the Node.h file is for declaration. The professor's examples include using both .h and .hpp files in a similar fashion.

I've tried removing include "Node.hpp" at the end of **Node.h**. This creates a new set of errors.

Questions:

1. What part of declaring template functions/classes am I not understanding properly?
2. How should I be approach solving these compilation errors on Cygwin?

**Node.h File**

```
#ifndef NODE_HEADER
#define NODE_HEADER

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <typename value_type>
class Node {
    public:
        
        //Constructor
        Node(value_type& newData, Node<value_type>* next = NULL, Node<value_type>* prev = NULL);
        //Setter for data
        void setData(value_type newData);
        //Setter for next
        void setNext(Node<value_type>* next);
        //Setter for previous
        void setPrev(Node<value_type>* prev);
        //Accessor for data
        value_type& getData() const;
        //Accessor for next
        Node<value_type>* getNext() const;
        //Accessor for prev
        Node<value_type>* getPrev() const;
        
        //Destructor
        ~Node();
        
        
    private:
        Node<value_type>* n;
        Node<value_type>* p;
        value_type* data;
    
};

template <typename value_type>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, Node<value_type>* n);

#include "Node.hpp"
#endif
```

**Node.hpp File**

```
#ifndef NODE_HEADER
#define NODE_HEADER

#include "Node.h"


//Constructor
template <typename value_type>
Node<value_type>::Node(value_type& newData, Node* next, Node* prev) {
    data = new value_type;
    *data = newData;
    n = next;
    p = prev;
}

//Setter for data
template <typename value_type>
void Node<value_type>::setData(value_type newData) {
    delete data;
    data = new value_type;
    *data = newData;
}

//Setter for next
template <typename value_type>
void Node<value_type>::setNext(Node* next) {
    n = next;
}

//Setter for previous
template <typename value_type>
void Node<value_type>::setPrev(Node* prev) {
    p = prev;
}

//Accessor for data
template <typename value_type>
value_type& Node<value_type>::getData() const {
    return *data;
}

//Accessor for next
template <typename value_type>
Node<value_type>* Node<value_type>::getNext() const {
    return n;
}

//Accessor for prev
template <typename value_type>
Node<value_type>* Node<value_type>::getPrev() const {
    return p;
}

template <typename value_type>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, Node<value_type>* n) {
    out << n->getData();
    return out;
}

//Destructor
template <typename value_type>
Node<value_type>::~Node() {delete data;}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

*makefile*

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++98 
LDFL

AGS=
SOURCES=Node.h main.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=main

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
    
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o core
```

Please note, I'm new to using templates in C++ and I'm required to compile through cygwin as per my university lecturer.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes it was a copy error, thanks! Updated.

Comment: I'd try not including node.h in node.hpp. Looks like a circular include issue.

Comment: Also, the lack of header guards in node.hpp is odd.

Comment: @cigien Thanks I've updated it with the header guards.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried taking out '#include "node.h"' in node.hpp, and got 2 sets of errors

**1)** 'Node' does not name a type for functions with:              Node<value_type>:: 

**2)** expected initializer before '<' token for functions with:     void Node<value_type>::

Comment: The include guard for `Node.hpp` should not use the same macro as the include guard for `Node.h` since you do want both included at some point. Having `Node.hpp` include `Node.h` might be a good idea since there is no easy way to tell that one should not `#include "Node.hpp"` directly. (Using `.hpp` for the implementation and `.h` for the declaration is not a universal convention -- possibly it's not recognized outside your professor's classroom. So someone seeing the file name `Node.hpp` might think that should be included directly.) The include guards should prevent problems from that.

Comment: I tried to replicate your result, but did not get a compiler error. Could you provide the commands generated by your makefile (e.g. one might be `g++ -c -Wall -std=c++98 -c main.cpp`)?